# How to send scandinavian letters using SendInput

Tags: c#, sendinput

I'm trying to create a virtual keyboard, which simulates keyboard using the SendInput method like this:

```
        public static void SendKeyDown(System.Windows.Forms.Keys key)
        {
            INPUT k = new INPUT();
            k.type = (int)InputType.INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            k.ki.wVk = (short)key;
            k.ki.dwFlags = (int)KEYEVENTF.KEYDOWN;
            k.ki.dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo();

            SendInput(1, new INPUT[] { k }, Marshal.SizeOf(k));
        }
```

But I cannot find the scandinavian letters Ä,Ö and Å from the Keys -enumeration. How can I send these letters using the SendInput method?

Comment: You're a computer programmer: *write a program* to answer your question. Write a form that handles the KeyDown event and displays the KeyEventArgs.KeyCode property, press the key, see what happens.

Comment: Yeah! Why didn't I thought of that!?! Thanks! :)

Comment: And the right answer was: Oem3 = ö, Oem7 = ä, Oem6 = å

Comment: Now, remember, those codes are only valid if your customer has the same keyboard as you. "OEM" means "Original Equipment Manufacturer"; the maker of the keyboard gets to decide what the key bindings are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send Unicode characters using `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE`.

```
k.type = (int)InputType.INPUT_KEYBOARD;
k.ki.wScan = 'ö';
k.ki.wVk = 0;
k.ki.dwFlags = (int)KEYEVENTF.UNICODE | (int)KEYEVENTF.KEYDOWN;
k.ki.dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo();
```

This is more portable than your solution of using `Oem3` et al, whose assigned character would vary according to the culture of the platform on which your application is executing.

(Rest of P/Invoke signatures can be found in my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8885228/1149773).)

Comment: Just note that when using `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE`, `wScan` is a UTF-16 codeunit.  If you want to send a Unicode codepoint that requires a UTF-16 surrogate pair (`ö` does not), you have to send two events, one for each codeunit of the pair.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution myself:

Oem3 = ö, Oem7 = ä, Oem6 = å