# Sending strings to inactive windows using C#

Tags: c#, winapi, sendmessage

I'm making a program that can send mouse click, keyboard input and strings to game windows (even if the window is **inactive**).

‍

I use `SendMessage` to send mouse click and keyboard input, it works fine.

But when I try to send strings to window, I found that it can't send the entire string at the same time (only send one char each time).

Here's the code I'm using:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern uint SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

public static void sendString(IntPtr hWnd, string s)
{
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        SendMessage(hWnd, (int)WM_CHAR, (int)c, 0);
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sendString(handle, "中文 string");
}
```

It works like:

```
中
中文
中文 
中文 s
中文 st
```

...and so on

but what I expect is to send "中文 string" at the same time.

I've tried:

```
SendMessage(handle, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "中文 string");
```

but it changes the window title (the game is a DirectX application, and the textbox does not have its own handle).

and also tried:

```
SendKeys.Send("中文 string");
```

or [Douglas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8885228/2075711), but those only works when the window is actived.

‍

I've googled for many answers and still can't find the best way, and I don't want to use copy & paste.

So if there is a way to send entire string at the same time to window that is inactive by using C#?

(I saw someone made a program by using EYuYan([易語言](http://www.eyuyan.com/)), and his tool can achieve my desired effect, so I think there must be a solution for C#)

Comment: Use WM_SETTEXT could only work if the handle is a child EDIT control.  But you already know it is not, nothing unusual in DirectX games.  There is nothing wrong with a for() loop, do what works.

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/30/423202.aspx).